# Storing tree structure with node attributes in database Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a hierarchical data set where parent nodes would have attributes x and y, while the leaf nodes would have attribute z. In simpler terms, my tree structure would look as follows:

```
                       ROOT
                      /    \ 
          [x,y] Node 1          [x,y] Node 2
          /       \                   \
[x,y] Node 1.1     [z] Node 1.2      [z] Node 2.1
      /          
 [z] Node 1.1.1
```

I need to store this in a database, but I am not sure how. I found the following post [about how to store a tree structure in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree?rq=1), but I don't see how I can use either of them to also store the attributes of each node. Any tips would be most welcome. I am using PostgreSql.

Comment: `create table graph (id integer primary key, parent_node integer references graph, x integer, y integer, z integer);` essentially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22376973/330315

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name said, but I would use `id serial primary key` instead ;)

Comment: Which path did you take for this problem and what was the outcome?